# Pre-process Laravel 4 view

Tags: preprocessor, laravel, laravel-4

I want to pre-process the views before they are rendered by processing them and generating a new file, and then make it load the new file instead.

I've looked at Packages/Service providers or creating a custom View class which extends some class in `Illuminate\View` and hijack it with `App::bind('view', 'CustomView')`, but neither seems to work the way I want.

Is this possible somehow?

**Example:**

1. `View::make('some_view');`
2. Check if `some_view` has changed, if so pre-process and save the result in some cache dir, e.g. `app/storage/cache/some_view.blade.php`.
3. Make `View` load `app/storage/cache/some_view.blade.php` instead.

Comment: Are you attempting to cache the rendered view, or do some other pre-processing to it?  Laravel already caches the compiled templates as PHP; but not the rendered output.  If this is the case then it may be better to consider writing your own CachedView class that wraps the view with some caching.

Comment: @PhillSparks I want to pre-process for translation, with a custom translation markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try `View::swap(new CustomView);`

all facades has the swap() available. I have used it myself to swap the Hash function with my own class so I could use Laravel with an existing project.

Comment: I can't figure out what class CustomView should extend, any ideas?

Comment: I see that is not as easy as extending the hash function, can't help you here!